# How does boxing a trait affect lifetime of parameters passed to it ? (with a very specific example)

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime, boxing

Here is a very simple but specific example that produces a compilation error I cannot understand:

```rust
use std::path::Path;

trait MyTrait<T> {
    fn my_func(&self, t: T);
}

struct MyImpl {}

impl MyTrait<&Path> for MyImpl {
    fn my_func(&self, t: &Path) {
        println!("{:?}", t)
    }
}

struct MyWrapper<T> {
    inner: Box<dyn MyTrait<T>>
}

impl<T> MyWrapper<T> {
    pub fn new(inner: Box::<dyn MyTrait<T>> ) -> Self { 
        Self { inner } 
    }
}

impl<T> MyTrait<T> for MyWrapper<T> {
    fn my_func(&self, t: T) {
        self.inner.my_func(t);
    }
}

fn foobar() {
    let the_impl = MyImpl{};        
    //let the_impl = MyWrapper::new(Box::new(the_impl)); // (*) 
    
    for entry in walkdir::WalkDir::new("blah") {
        let entry = entry.unwrap(); 
        let path = entry.path(); // <== here
        the_impl.my_func(path);
    }
}
```

When the line marked (*) is commented, everything is fine. However, if uncommented, the compiler complains about `entry` not living long enough, see the line marked "here".

I fail to understand how the wrapper happens to change the way the path is borrowed.

**EDIT**

As pointed out by @Jmb below, this has nothing to do with `Path`, and the same problem arises with a simple `&str`, for example:

```rust
impl MyTrait<&str> for MyImpl {
    fn my_func(&self, t: &str) {
        println!("{:?}", t)
    }
}

fn foobar_str() {
    let the_impl = MyImpl{};        
    let the_impl = MyWrapper::new(Box::new(the_impl));
    {
        let s = String::from("blah").clone();
        the_impl.my_func(&s as &str); // <== same error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the previous answer and comments provide very useful insights about lifetime inferences in this particular case, they don't come with a practical solution.

I finally found out the following one. First let's simplify a bit the problem, using a `String` for now:

```rust
trait MyTrait<T> { fn my_func(&self, t: T); }

struct MyImpl {}

impl MyTrait<&String> for MyImpl {
    fn my_func(&self, t: &String) { println!("{}", t) }
}

struct MyWrapper<T> { inner: Box<dyn MyTrait<T>> }

impl<T> MyTrait<T> for MyWrapper<T> {
    fn my_func(&self, t: T) { self.inner.my_func(t); }
}
```

Of course it fails exactly for the same reason as before:

```rust
fn foobar() {
    let the_impl = MyImpl{};
    let the_impl = MyWrapper { inner: Box::new(the_impl) };
    {
        let s = String::from("blah");
        the_impl.my_func(&s); // <== error: 's' does not live long enough
    }
}
```

However, if one changes `MyTrait` so `T` is passed by reference in the signature of `my_func`, and adapts the rest accordingly:

```rust
trait MyTrait<T> { fn my_func(&self, t: &T); } // <== main change here

struct MyImpl {}

impl MyTrait<String> for MyImpl {
    fn my_func(&self, t: &String) { println!("{}", t) } // <== note the actual signature hasn't changed
}

struct MyWrapper<T> { inner: Box<dyn MyTrait<T>> }

impl<T> MyTrait<T> for MyWrapper<T> {
    fn my_func(&self, t: &T) { self.inner.my_func(t); }
}
```

Then the `foobar()` function can be left unchanged, **but now it compiles**.

And, as stated by @kmdreko below, it will also work for `str` or or other non-sized types like `Path`, with the following modifications:

```rust
trait MyTrait<T: ?Sized> { fn my_func(&self, t: &T); }

struct MyWrapper<T: ?Sized> { inner: Box<dyn MyTrait<T>> }

impl<T: ?Sized> MyTrait<T> for MyWrapper<T> {
    fn my_func(&self, t: &T) { self.inner.my_func(t); }
}
```

Then, to come back to the initial use case, the following code now works as expected:

```rust
impl MyTrait<Path> for MyImpl {
      fn my_func(&self, t: &Path) { println!("{:?}", t) }
}

fn foobar_with_path_in_a_loop() {
    let the_impl = MyImpl{};        
    let the_impl = MyWrapper { inner: Box::new(the_impl) };
    
    for entry in walkdir::WalkDir::new("blah") {
        let entry = entry.unwrap();
        let path = entry.path();
        the_impl.my_func(path);
    }
}
```

**Bottomline**

See @Jmb's answer and associated comments for some explanations about why the first solution doesn't compile.

Comment: *"Of course it won't work for `str` or any non-sized type like `Path`, but it can still be a workaround for most cases."* - you can relax that restriction by using `T: ?Sized` in your trait and wherever else.

Comment: Indeed thanks @kmdreko ! And after more testing on my real use case it appears that this solution actually addresses my initial requirements very well. The only drawback would be that one couldn't pass a `T` by value, but that's unlikely to be a real problem. I'm going edit the answer accordingly and mark my problem as solved.

Answer (score 4):

`path` has type `&'a Path` for some lifetime `'a` that is only valid for a single loop iteration (until `entry` gets dropped).

When wrapped in your wrapper, `the_impl` has type `MyWrapper<T>` for some inferred type `T`.

Since you call `the_impl.my_func (path)` the compiler infers that `T == &'a Path`, so `the_impl` has type `MyWrapper<&'a Path>`, which can't exist for longer than the `'a` lifetime. Hence the error since `the_impl` needs to exist for the whole loop.

When you don't wrap `the_impl`, it has type `MyImpl` which implements `MyTrait<&'b Path>` *for all lifetimes `'b`*, including lifetimes that are shorter than the lifetime of `the_impl` (they only need to be long enough for the call to `my_func`). So the compiler can use the `MyTrait<&'a Path>` implementation, without affecting the lifetime of `the_impl`.

There is nothing special with the `Path` type here, but there may be with your `&str` implementation. I suspect that in the latter case you wound up with `&'static str`, which can live forever if needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. You were right about `str`, I was mislead by an implicit `static` one. I modified and completed by question accordingly.

However, although I understand all these lifetime considerations, I still don't get why the compiler makes two different assumptions on each case. **And more importantly : why does it consider that the value is borrowed by `my_func`, as it is passed by reference anyway ?** Also, do you have a suggestion about how to correct the code to make it work ? Thanks again

Comment: As to why the compiler infers the lifetime differently, it's because conversion to a trait object requires that the trait implementation (including generic lifetimes) is encoded in the type of the trait object, which means the `&Path` part of the trait's type _must_ have a single lifetime. This means that all the references passed to the trait method _need to have the same lifetime_ but they do not. When you don't convert it to a trait object, the compiler is free to use a different lifetime on each loop iteration, because the lifetime is not permanently encoded anywhere.

Comment: Note that if you box into a `Box<dyn for<'a> MyTrait<&'a Path>>` that it works, which illustrates the above point. Passing this box into `MyWrapper` breaks it again, indicating that it's not trait objects in general that are the problem, but that the type of the trait object in `MyWrapper` is too inflexible -- there is not a single `T` that works for all loop iterations.

Comment: Thank you @cdowie, it's much clearer now for why the two cases are different, and btw it brought the `for<'x>` syntax to my knowledge. However it's a bit frustrating as it feels like a Rust "limitation", and also it doesn't explain why the compiler sees a borrow when passing a reference (correct me if I'm wrong). I have a kinda workaround that I'm about to post as a potential answer (because it doesn't fit in the comments), and that lets me believe that the compiler happens to think it's a borrow because of the way I defined the trait. I'd be happy to have your thought on it.

Comment: @fruphon *"it doesn't explain why the compiler sees a borrow when passing a reference"* - a "borrow" and a "reference" are synonymous, they mean the same thing

Comment: @kmdreko Yes, sorry, I meant "why it appears to be *still borrowed* at the end of the block".

Comment: @kmdreko But ok I think I see now that it's a matter of lifetime of this particular object that comes to be associated with the one of the trait object... However it's not 100% clear for me why the solution I proposed an answer.

Comment: But _who required `MyWrapper<&'a Path>` to live longer than `'a`_? Nobody's doing that. So it should have worked fine. The real problem is more complicated.

Comment: @fruphon It's still borrowed because it has to be. The compiler is deducing the size of the lifetime like this: (A) because the `T` can't change between iterations, it must have one specific lifetime; (B) because a reference is passed in in a loop, the only way to make `T` be the same for all iterations is if the lifetime of all references outlive the loop; (C) because the lifetime outlives the loop, the borrow held by `path` must outlive the loop; (D) `path` borrows from `entry` which does not outlive the loop. C and D contradict each other, so you get an error.

Comment: @fruphon It's also worth noting that if the compiler didn't detect the contradiction between C and D, there could be a soundness issue where nothing would prevent `the_impl` from holding a reference for longer than it is valid. So while _this_ code is fine, similar code with exactly the same types and function signatures but with different struct members and function bodies could be unsound. Consider if `MyImpl` had a `T` member that it copied `t` into from within `my_func`. The borrow would easily outlive the loop, even though `entry` is dropped. This is what Rust is protecting you from.

Comment: Yes @cdhowie, I think I understand this quite well, that's Rust basics. Which state that a struct cannot keep a copy of some borrowed ref unless it specifies the appropriate lifetime constraints. So `MyImpl` could not hold a reference to `t` without these, and there is no reason for the compiler to infer that it should last as long as the `MyImpl` instance it was passed to. And indeed it works perfectly until `MyWrapper` comes into play. For the reason you explained, I believe, and thanks for that. However this issue is solved by the answer I described thereafter (and I'm not sure why).

Comment: @fruphon It works, simply, because `T` doesn't contain a lifetime -- `T` becomes `Path` instead of `&Path`.